# Use javascript function from within lightbox content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use fancybox to open ajax content in a lightbox. Sometimes my newly loaded content contains some JS code. How can I use the JS functions that are already loaded in my main js-file from the ajax content?

My current way of solving it is creating jQuery plugins in my JS file, but that seems dirty. Example in my JS file:

```
$.fn.arrayRemove = function(arr, value)
{
   return arr.filter(function(ele) {
       return ele != value;
   });

};
```

If I would just write the below code, the function arrayRemove() would not be reachable from the ajax content. Makes sense?

```
function arrayRemove(arr, value)
{
   return arr.filter(function(ele) {
       return ele != value;
   });

}
```

Comment: I think you can add your functions to window object as variables and use them from your ajax content.

Comment: @MuraliNepalli Thanks! How do I do that?

Comment: add your method "mainJsFunc1"   to window object like this.  window.mainJsFunc1 = mainJsFunc1. in your ajax content try calling window.mainJsFunc1("params");